# Using Folders.Add Vs AddSubFolder inside my CSOM code

Tags: development, csom

I have the following CSOM code to get the root folder:-

```
  var folder = list.RootFolder.Folders.Add("A");
```

but to add a sub-folder seems there is 2 ways:-

```
folder.Folders.Add("B");
```

OR

```
folder.AddSubFolder("B");
```

so what is the main difference between `Folders.Add` and `AddSubFolder`  and which one is faster?